# How do I perform a nearly "full system" backup on Debian Stretch using rsync?

Tags: debian, rsync, backup, backintime

I have compiled and installed [Back In Time](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime) to perform automated, full, system backups of my desktop computer running Debian Stretch (kernel 4.90.0-8-amd64).  Back In Time uses `rsync` under the hood. When I run a full system backup after clicking the button `Modify for Full System Backup` it throws a few errors about symlinks and other files it has problems copying.

I decided to figure out the exact options required to pass to `rysnc`, so that I can have greater control over how Back In Time performs the backup.  I would like to backup everything on my drive except for:

- /home/*
- /opt/*
- /media/*
- any other system files that should not be included in the backup

Here is the command I think I need to run, but I'm not sure if I have it completely correct.  Can you see any problems with my proposed `rsync` command?

`rsync -rptgoEAXl --safe-links --inplace  -F --exclude /opt/* --exclude /home/* --exclude /media/* --exclude /tmp/* --exclude  /var/tmp/* --exclude /var/backups/* --exclude /etc/mtab --exclude /proc/* --exclude /run/* --exclude *~ --exclude [Tt]rash* --exclude /dev/* --exclude lost+found/* --exclude .Private / /media/username/USB/my_backup_folder`

**Note:** I have read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424208/how-to-do-a-full-incremental-and-searchable-backup-of-the-entire-hard-drive-and/424259#424259), but it does not suite my needs because it uses `dd` and not `rsync`.

**P.S.:** my backup drive is an external USB disk, and is formatted as `exfat` on a `gpt` partition. I'll be re-doing my backup drive later to use `ext4` on a `gpt` partition, but I can not do that until I get this backup in taken care of.  Kind of a catch 22.

**UPDATE**

Added a solution, see below.

Answer (score 1):

Through trial and error, reading [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158493/what-should-i-include-and-exclude-with-rsync-to-back-up-my-system), and reading the man pages on `rsync` I was able to get it to work.  I'll post a proper solution when stackexchange.com allows me to.  For now here's what I did:

1. Used a different external USB drive that is formatted at `ext4`, so that file permissions and extended attributes will be copied.
2. Used the following command:

`rsync -rtDHh --checksum --links -A -X -pEgo --info=progress2 --no-i-r  --delete --delete-excluded  -v  --chmod=Du+wx  --exclude="/root/.local/share/backintime" --exclude=".local/share/backintime/mnt"  --exclude=".gvfs" --exclude=".cache/*" --exclude=".thumbnails*" --exclude="[Tt]rash*" --exclude="*.backup*" --exclude="*~" --exclude=".dropbox*" --exclude="/proc/*" --exclude="/sys/*" --exclude="/dev/*" --exclude="/run/*" --exclude="/etc/mtab" --exclude="/var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb" --exclude="lost+found/*" --exclude="/tmp/*" --exclude="/var/tmp/*" --exclude="/var/backups/*" --exclude=".Private" --exclude="/opt" --exclude="/home" --exclude="/media" --include="/" --include="/**" --exclude="*" / "/media/username/USB/full-system-backup/"`